# How to validate csv file has an empty row in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this script able to read the csv file this is running completely, but now I want to validate it first. Before uploading I want to check the every data on the row. If the data found an empty on the row it will throw an error. I've tried many validation but it seems it lacking.

This is my script on uploading:

```
if(!empty($_FILES["charge_file"]["name"])){

        $file = explode('.', $_FILES['charge_file']['name']);
        $csvfile = end($file);
        $csvfile_ext = array('csv');

        if(in_array($csvfile, $csvfile_ext)){                       


        $handle = fopen($_FILES["charge_file"]["tmp_name"],"r");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {


                $chrg_empid = $data[0];
                $chrg_empname = $data[1];
                $chrgemp_name = utf8_encode($chrg_empname);
                $chrg_cvf = $data[2];
                $chrg_amount = $data[3];
                $chrg_store = $data[4];
                $chrg_date = $data[5];                          
                $chrg_installment = $data[6];
                $chrg_ded_type = $data[7];

                charges_individual_entry($chrg_empid, $chrg_empname, $chrg_cvf, $chrg_amount, $chrg_store, $ent_date, $chrg_ded_type, $chrg_installment);



            }

            // echo "success";

            fclose($handle);

        }
        else{   
            echo 'invalid';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'select';
    }
```

This my function in inserting:

```
function charges_individual_entry($chrg_empid, $chrg_empname, $chrg_cvf, $chrg_amount, $chrg_store, $ent_date, $chrg_ded_type, $chrg_installment){

    $db = database2();
    $query = "INSERT INTO CFV_ENTRY (EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, REF_NO, AMOUNT, STORES, TRXN_DATE, DED_TYPE, NO_INSTALLMENT, DATE_INSERTED, ENTRY_TYPE, ENTRY_DESC) VALUES ('$chrg_empid', '$chrg_empname', '$chrg_cvf', '$chrg_amount', '$chrg_store', '$ent_date', '$chrg_ded_type', '$chrg_installment', SYSDATE, '1', 'CHARGE')";
    $cmd = $db->prepare($query);
    $cmd->execute();
    $db = null;

}
```

This is my validation:

```
function isEmptyFields($csv_file){

$handle = fopen($csv_file,"r");

    $counter = 0;

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $counter = $counter + 1;

        if ($data[0] != null) {

            if ($data[1] != null) {

                if($data[2] != null){

                    if ($data[3] != null) {

                        if($data[4] != null){

                            if($data[5] != null){

                                if($data[6] != null){

                                    if($data[7] != null){



                                        // echo $chrg_empid = $data[0];
                                        echo 'success';

                            //          echo $chrg_empid = $data[0]."\n";
                                        // $chrg_empname = $data[1]."\n";
                                        // echo $chrgemp_name = utf8_encode($chrg_empname)."\n";
                                        // echo $chrg_cvf = $data[2]."\n";
                                        // echo $chrg_amount = $data[3]."\n";
                                        // echo $chrg_store = $data[4]."\n";
                                        // echo $chrg_date = $data[5]."\n";
                                        // echo $chrg_installment = $data[6]."\n";
                                        // echo $chrg_ded_type = $data[7]."\n";


                                    }else{
                                        echo 'Empty field is in line: '.$counter; 
                                    }

                                }else{
                                    echo 'Empty field is in line: '.$counter;
                                }

                            }else{
                                echo 'Empty field is in line: '.$counter;
                            }

                        }else{
                            echo 'Empty field is in line: '.$counter;
                        }

                    }else{
                        echo 'Empty field is in line: '.$counter;
                    }

                }else{
                    echo 'Empty field is in line: '.$counter;
                }

            }else{

                echo 'Empty field is in line: '.$counter;
            }

        }else{
            echo 'Empty field is in line: '.$counter;
        }

    }


    // fclose($handle);

// return $handle;

}
```

Comment: your code is open to **SQL injection attacks** - use parameterised statements to secure your database - you're already preparing them, why not make that one extra step that also greatly improves performance and readability?

Comment: soon it will improve, but for now i want to solve the problem first.

Comment: _"I've tried many validation but it seems it lacking"_ - Please share what you've tried and explain what happened when you did.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i update my validation please see

Comment: Do you want to throw an error if _any_ of the fields are empty in a row, or do you want to throw an error only if _all_ of the fields are empty in a row?

Comment: to throw an error if one field is empty on a row.

Comment: If you want to parse the CSV file and validate, then use papa parse js library for client side csv parsing. It has huge features, so you can validate date before actual upload.

Comment: @Ayan_84 - The OP would still need to validate it server side as well.

Comment: "soon it will improve" no, it will not. there's not reason whatsoever _not_ use parameterised statements, and putting it off for later just guarantees that you will forget it. it's never too soon to do it the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that goes through the row and checks if any of the elements are empty.

```
function hasEmptyField(array $data, int $field_count)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $field_count; $i++) {
        // Make sure that the key exists, isn't null or an empty string
        if (!isset($data[$i]) || $data[$i] === '') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

You can use that function in your `while`-loop:

```
$counter = 0;

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {        

    $counter++;    

    if (hasEmptyField($data, 7)) {
        // It has an empty field. Echo an error and skip to next row
         echo 'Empty field is in line: ' . $counter; 
         continue;
    }

    $chrg_empid       = $data[0];
    $chrg_empname     = $data[1];
    $chrgemp_name     = utf8_encode($chrg_empname);
    $chrg_cvf         = $data[2];
    $chrg_amount      = $data[3];
    $chrg_store       = $data[4];
    $chrg_date        = $data[5];                          
    $chrg_installment = $data[6];
    $chrg_ded_type    = $data[7];

    charges_individual_entry($chrg_empid, $chrg_empname, $chrg_cvf, $chrg_amount, $chrg_store, $ent_date, $chrg_ded_type, $chrg_installment);
}
```

Comment: where do i put my insert function there?

Comment: @rjjvillareal - Where it says: `// your current insert code`.

Comment: Erikson - could you check it?

Comment: @rjjvillareal - It looks correct. If it works for you, please accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Following checks for any empty row and skip it

```
$file_path="path/to/csvfile.csv";
if (($handle = fopen($file_path , "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if (array(null) !== $data) {
            //process lines which are not blank
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question asked. For some reason this code is only checking whether array contains only one element which is null. Doesn't make any sesne

Answer (score -1):

Try the following -

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $counter++;
    foreach($data as $entry) {
        if(!$entry) {
            echo "Error on line $counter";
            break;
        }
    }
    //other code goes here
}
```

Comment: This answer has many issues and better be deleted